# Android app does not discover NFC tag if phone already next to it

Tags: android, nfc

Imagine the following scenario:
The app which reads the content of the NFC tag has not been started. My phone is next to the tag. I start the app, and expect the "readTag" activity to read my tag, but it doesn't. It only works if I move my phone away from the tag, and place it next to the tag again.

I imagine the reason for this to be because ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED event has already happened. Re-positioning the phone then helps because the app is running and the ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED happens again.

If I use the

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

my app will start when the tag has been discovered, but it only opens the "readTag" activity. I still then have to reposition the phone to read the payload out.

I was able to reproduce the same behaviour with the "NFC Tools" and my own app.

Does anyone have an explanation for this, or am I missing something?

Comment: post the code of your `readTag` activity

Answer (score 0):

For the case where your "readTag" activity is started due to the `NDEF_DISCOVERED` intent filter, you are obviously missing something. You will receive the `Tag` object (and the `NdefMessage`) that triggered the intent as part of the intent extras. Thus, you just need to get the intent that started your activity (this can be retrieved with `Activity.getIntent()`), extract the relevant intent extra (e.g. `Tag` object) and pass it to your tag processing:

```
public void onStart() {
    ...
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    processTag(tag);
}
```

For the case where your activity is manually started, there is no official way to access the tag without physically re-attaching it to the device. However, there seems to be an undocumented feature (or maybe just a bug!?) with the Reader Mode API that was introduced in Android 4.4: Whenever the reader mode API is disabled/enabled the tag will be redetected. Thus, you could implement a mechanism to force re-discovery of tags when your activity is started.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I forgot a case in my procesTag(..) function.

Now I have

```
public void procesTag(Intent intent) {   
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()) ||
            NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    ...
```

instead of

```
public void procesTag(Intent intent) {   
    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction()) {
    ...
```

since I am using a NDEF_DISCOVERED intent. Otherwise, the tag was ignored.